# How to add 2 different contextual filters to a view

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a page view that displays a list of jobs. I want to be able to filter on SECTOR and REGION. When I add a contextual filter to my jobpage view for sector it works perfectly, however when I add the second one, region, it doesn't display anything.

[image]

Clicking on "Diensten" goes to my page view and displays all jobs tagged with "Diensten". However when I click a region, it doesn't display any jobs, only when I make sure the region contextual filter is above the sector one. How can I get this to work?

I use Taxonomy name to ID in my contextual filtering

Comment: Check this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87277/create-2-or-more-exposed-filters-for-the-same-view , if it helps

Comment: You can add two contextual filter in view without any problem. You should remember the order of the arguments  and contextual filter be same so that you will get correct data.

Comment: I've tried to play around with it but nothing seems to work. I've added my second contextual filter the exact same way as my first one, only I selected a different vocabulary. Do you happen to know what I could be doing wrong? My sector contextual filter works fine but my region filter gives the results back listed in "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL"

Comment: @YassinTahtah, Please share you export view. I hope you  that url for the views would be 'www.example.com/[viewspat]/[arg1]/[arg2]'

Comment: Not exactly, how should I put it? My sector field outputs a link: jobsview/[name] and so does my region field. What should I do to change it?

Comment: I guess my question is how do I name the args? Because as for now I've been using [name] to display the name in url